# Problems with responsive email templates

Tags: html, email

I recently made a responsive email template. I have img links in it that calls images from my local hard drive. When I send the email template to an email address, I can only seem to send the html file that contains the codes, and not the image files as well. This makes the images to not get loaded. Is there a way for these images to be somehow combined into one file, instead of being in two groups of files (html and a folder of images)?

Thank you.

Comment: Basically I am trying to do the same thing as the person who posted the first post in this link:

http://www.tectite.com/vbforums/showthread.php?1911-Images-in-HTML-Email-Template

They don't seem to have found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 2 ways to include images in html email.

1. Host the images online (http://www.yoursite.com/link/to/yourimage.jpg for example) - This is industry standard. Users will have to load the images if diplay images is not set by default, or the sender is not in your safe list.
2. Embed the image using [Base64](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3927/embedded-images-in-html-email) - This makes your email slow to load, but the image will load by default.

Answer (score 1):

You could host the images online and use the links in the html email. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this method :)

Answer (score 0):

i hope u can use any server for the images,

its unable to load images from local server while sending the mail

https://cloudinary.com/ is one of best and cheap server available and flexible too

http://res.cloudinary.com/cartoon-mango/image/upload/v1453296305/Urdoorstep/20116/2.png